# Uniswap getPair() does not deliver address(0)

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am currently testing the Uniswap function getPair()

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => address)) public override getPair;
```

and calling it from UI like this:

```
   const pairAddress = await this.state.factory.getPair(
            this.state.tokenAData.address,
            this.state.tokenBData.address
          );
```

For some reason, I am not always getting address(0) like in the [documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses) explained.

Using ether.js to create the instance:

```
 const factory = new ethers.Contract(
    this.isAddress(REACT_APP_FACTORY_ADDRESS),
    Factory.abi,
    signer
  );
```

I deployed a fresh contract and cleared and removed the cache but getting always an address, eg. "0x23De993d........". Is there any other way to find out if the pair address exists or not?

Comment: 1) What network are you connected to (Ethereum mainnet, Ropsten testnet, BSC mainnet, ...)? 2) What factory address are you passing to the `Contract` constructor as the first argument? 3) What are the token addresses that you're passing to the `getPair()` arguments?

Comment: 1) BSC testnet over moralis 2) 0xCf8862BBF85621f38D2f4c5AcC4Ae1D3D088721F  3) 0x45b5ECbb4d0283A21Ca2Fdf5BE3FE2eF20285109 0x8C8E146a1ecB8e24BF4885fB0C387cBd15d59A7a

Answer (score 0):

```
//import FACTORY_ADDRESS from config.js file,
//import FACTORY_ABI from constant.js

  //initialize the provider, siger and account
    const provider = new ethers.proviers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.JSON_RPC);
    const singer= new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
    const account = singer.connect(provider);
    
    //create an instance of a contract
    const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
        config.FACTORY_ADDRESS,
        FACTORY_ABI,
        account
    );
    
    //create a function to get the pair address
    const pairAddress = async (tokenA, tokenB) {
      try{
         let pair = await factoryContract.getPair(tokenA, tokenB)
        }
       catch(error){
        console.log(error)
       }
      }

 //call in the function passing the parameters 1.e tokenA and tokenB
   const pairAddress = await pairAddress(
        this.state.tokenAData.address,
        this.state.tokenBData.address
       )
```